# Set up function with optional input parameter (swift)

Tags: swift

Can i set up function with optional input parameter? that means when i call that function, i can either pass the parameter or not to pass the parameter.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can supply a default parameter value, in which case you can leave the parameter off at the call site:

```
func someFunction(someParam: Int = 12) {
    print(someParam)
}

someFunction(10)

someFunction()
```

You can combine this with `Optional` to default to `nil`:

```
func someFunction(someParam: Int? = nil) {
    if let x = someParam {
        print(x)
    }
    else {
        print("no param given")
    }
}
```

Parameters with default values should be placed at the end of the parameter list.